# DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames adding a dot at the end of month's name

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

Last night we migrated our web services tier from physical Windows 2008 r2 to virtual Windows 2012.

We are getting tons of events on ours logs about DateTime's invalid formats, strange as we double checked our regional settings.

Long story short:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-MX").DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames
```

Outputs (using LinqPad5):

1. ene.
2. feb.
3. mar.

on our new 2012 env while on 2008 ouptus:

1. ene
2. feb
3. mar

Our parsing is something like this:

```
DateTime.Parse("18 ene 16",CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-MX"))
```

And while it worked wonders now it throws

`FormatException : 
The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 3.`.

While

```
DateTime.Parse("18 ene. 16",CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-MX"))
```

works but isn't the expected input from our several clients.

Working on the same runtime version (4.0.30319.42000), double checked (again) our regional settings on both servers what else can I look for to fix this (before giving up and hacking it with a regex replace)?

Thanks.

Comment: Somebody probably changed the config in the old server many years ago.  You'll have to do it again on the new one.  Use Control Panel > Region.

Comment: Are you sure about the runtime version? 2008 R2 was delivered with 3.5.1 framework which outputs the abbr. names without a dot whereas 2012 is delivered with 4.5 framework that outputs the abbr. names with a dot. you could try to change the framework version (if possible) to 3.5?

Comment: @HansPassant: yeah, we are checking both configs again, I'll let you know if I find something.

Comment: @Uwe: I tested it with a script of linqpad and gave me that output on both servers, both app pools are configured as .NET Framework v4.0 but downgrading the new one to 3.5 could do the trick! I'll try and let you know! 
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly I couldn't find anything in the configuration that pointed me in the right direction.

Ended with a nasty hack like this:

```
var cultura = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-MX");
if (cultura.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames.First().EndsWith("."))
   cultura.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames = cultura.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames.Select(c => c.Substring(0, c.Length > 1 ? c.Length - 1 : 0)).ToArray();
```

and used that culture in the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, when scraping a web-element for a date.
The date looked like this "Fre 14. okt 2022".

Inspired by DSXP answer, I found this to be working:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("da-DK");

    cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames = cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames
        .Select(x => x.EndsWith(".") ? x.TrimEnd('.') : x)
        .ToArray();
```