# Culture Abbreviated month names end with period sometimes

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, culture

For a `CultureInfo`, calling `DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames` returns an array where each month ends in a `.` such as `['jan.',... 'dis.']`.

This doesn't occur on the build server and not on all developers machines either, just some. There seems to be no correlation to what the `CurrentCulture` and the machine location/language is set to.

The tests that pick this up are for a spanish culture and include explicitly creating a `CultureInfo` for spanish. So I would have thought that this information is hardcoded somewhere and is just being read out, and as far as I can tell it is. Being read from `CultureData.AbbreviatedMonthNames(calendarId)`.

Update:
Upon further investigation it seems that if the current culture at startup is `en-GB` then there are no periods. If it's `en-US` then there are. Explicitly setting the `CurrentCulture` has no effect, just if it's different at startup.

Comment: There is a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37354988/579895). What i would do is use my own abbreviatedmonthnames collection...

Answer (score 5):

You can use your own `AbbreviatedMonthNames` Collection so there would always be the same, like this:

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = ci.DateTimeFormat;
dtfi.AbbreviatedMonthNames = new string[] { "Jan.", "Feb.", "Mar.", 
                                              "Apr.", "May.", "Jun.", 
                                              "Jul.", "Aug.", "Sep.", 
                                              "Oct.", "Nov.", "Dec.", "" };  
dtfi.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = dtfi.AbbreviatedMonthNames;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy", dtfi));
```

Or change it in the current thread:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"));
```