ASP.NET Core 8 Web API : date formatting issue after migration from .NET Core 3.1
I've built an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API that will eventually replace an existing ASP.NET Core 3.1 project. The API serves various clients and is integrated with SQL Server.
When starting to test the API calls I've suddenly starting getting lots of DateTime formatting errors like this:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

After adding some code to write queries to a log file, I can see that DateTime values are being formatted differently - it is now mysteriously adding a full stop or dot after the abbreviated month name.
Example query that causes the error:
SELECT COUNT(*) AS myCount 
FROM member 
WHERE CreateDT >= '1 Jun. 2024 00:01'

The date part above is created by the following code:
DateTime.Today.ToString("d MMM yyyy");

Exact code that causes the error is just a string and formatted DateTime value:
DateTime dt_start = DateTime.Today;
string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS myCount FROM member WHERE CreateDT >= '" + dt_start.ToString("d MMM yyyy") + " 00:01'";

The strange thing is it's not happening when debugging on my test PC. The errors only happen on the server. But both my PC and the server have the same Region and Regional format.

After searching online, this seems to be due to the rules of the "current" culture format. However, I've not explicitly set a culture format.
Is there some code I need to add to Program.cs when configuring the web application and services? How do I fix this properly? I certainly don't want to just manually change all my .ToString() calls to remove the dot!

Have you tried ISO datetime formatting?

@DaleK I've added the exact code that produces the error - it's just a string variable with an SQL query that contains a formatted date. my code has not changed at all from the working .NET Core 3.1 project - which does NOT put a dot after the month name.

Hmm, but that is not the correct way to pass a parameter. If you passed the data correctly as a parameter you would not have this issue.

@DaleK the parameter is not a problem, it's just an SQL query. the point is that EVERY reference to a date value with .ToString("d MMM yyyy") in my project is now adding a dot after the abbreviated month. this does not happen in my Core3.1 project with the same code.

The lack of a correct SQL parameter is the problem, because parameters are not subject to date formats. String concatenation is not the correct way to build a query

Anyway, seems similar to this but different region https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354988/datetimeformat-abbreviatedmonthnames-adding-a-dot-at-the-end-of-months-name#37418476

You know it's easier to just use parameters than going through the formatting nonsense? YyyyMmdd or yyyy-Mm-ddTHH:MM:SS are teh format to use if you really have to use them

Stop concatenating string segments together with tainted user data in an attempt to form T-SQL queries.  Obligatory reference to Little Bobby Tables. SqlCommands have an SqlParameterCollection on them for a reason. Use parameters.

I am not concerned about the "correct" way to pass a parameter. I know what parameters are and how to use them. too many stupid comments on here fussing about question formatting, parameters, everything except the actual issue. forget about SQL. I need to know why .NET is suddenly adding full-stops to formatted date strings. they now appear in reports and headings, basically everywhere I use .ToString() on a date variable. if I don't get any real help in this post, I'll try posting again without any reference to SQL!!!

You probably should do exactly that. Improving your attitude wouldn't hurt either. Did you check the link I posted? It would seem to be related.

@DaleK I did check the link you posted and thanks I do appreciate any help/suggestions. the poster didn't find anything in the configuration that indicated why the date formatting changed and his solution was a hack. aside from the SQL issue, I have multiple problems resulting from .ToString() now adding a dot after the abbreviated month name. apologies for my abrupt/abrasive attitude.

This is a date formatting issue (not an SQL problem).
To fix it, add some middleware in the pipeline as follows. Note that, I put the code straight after CreateBuilder(args).
This code explicitly sets a culture and the abbreviated month names.
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-AU");
});

var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-AU");
cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames = new string[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "" };
cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = new string[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "" };
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

